# MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am attempting to run a meteor app, but I am getting a mongo error, not sure how to debug this

```
[~/sites/tuts]$ meteor --port 5555
[[[[[ ~/Sites/tuts ]]]]]

Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start mongod

MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
Check to make sure that MongoDB is able to write to its database directory.
```

Comment: exception : "Check to make sure that MongoDB is able to write to its database directory." .. Check the permission on the dir ??

Comment: It was working before and suddenly stopped? Do you have enough free disk space?

Comment: I Imaged the drive, partitioned it cloned it to the new partition reformatted the old one reinstalled osx cloned the repository, all working now.

Answer (score 15):

Mongo was killed without cleaning itself up. Try removing .meteor/local/db/mongod.lock. If that fails you can do an meteor reset, but that will wipe your database.

Comment: I should build you a shrine, kind sir.

Comment: And what if there is no .meteor/local/db folder, though it has 0777 and the owner is my current account?

Comment: I'd also suggest to check the meteor/local/db/ in general, with Dropbox I had loads of conflicts which filled the directory with garbage files, removing those fixed it.

Comment: In my case Mongo still would not start after removing the lock file. And I got a very cryptic error: "Unexpected mongo exit code null". It turned out that my database was corrupted. I couldn't repair it, but this may help some people: `mongod --repair --dbpath /database/db --storageEngine wiredTiger` ( see: http://superuser.com/a/914650 ).